# How to work with unbalanced datasets in generalized Boosted Regression Models using gbm?

Tags: r, gbm

I would like to know if there is a way to work with unbalanced datasets with generalized Boosted Regression Models. I'm using the `gbm` package.

I have 7 groups with a different number of sites and samples (e.g. group A: 15 sites, 309 samples; group B:26 sites, 662 samples). I have read that having unbalanced data will vias the results toward the group with more samples.

Does anybody any suggestion about how to deal with this?

Comment: My vague memory is that `gbm` is for iid data, so it doesn't particularly care if you have a balanced panel. Since you are worried about balance and bias, this question would be better for crossValidated or the data science stackexchange. I'm pretty sure that you can find some answers on those sites that relate to this problem.

Comment: Hi lmo, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: take a look at [1](https://www.r-bloggers.com/handling-class-imbalance-with-r-and-caret-an-introduction/), [2](https://topepo.github.io/caret/subsampling-for-class-imbalances.html) and [3](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/release/html/over_and_undersampling/index.html). Also there is no reason to use `gbm` when there is `xgboost`.

Comment: thanks for the links @missuse